# What kind of time format is this? i.e. 1493369050000

Tags: json, time, format

I have several times, formatted like this.

1493327653000
1493336648000
1493362453000

I just don't get which format this is. I just need to have everything in the same time format, that I can map them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just found out. It's UNIX Time in milliseconds.

*Should have waited for a second before posting this.*

Answer (score 0):

These all are the epoch time(UNIX time) in milliseconds.

[image]